# Cannot run simple HelloWorld node.js script

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

I have just installed node.js on my ubuntu laptop.

I followed the instructions found here: http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/05/06/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu/#application and installed from the git repository

Installed with no errors, but when I ran the server.js sample application program nothing happened.

Worse still, I tried to run a ver basic hello world script called hello.js

```
console.log("hello world");
```

When I type : node hello.js

nothing happens, there is no error message, nothing is written to the console window.

IS there any known issues with node on ubuntu?

thanks

**EDIT**

just noticed in terminal if I type:

```
node console.log("hello world");
```

I get

> > $ node console.log("hi");

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: what happens when you call localhost:1337 in your browser?

Comment: Chromium's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured. 127.0.0.1 works fine, ALso, I just noticed on command line I cant even call node -v . Just exits as before

Comment: What do you get from `which -a node`? You might have another `node` executable already in `PATH` and are running that instead of Node.js.

Comment: I get two lines of output: /usr/local/bin/node 
 :: and : /usr/sbin/node

Comment: Try `nodejs yourscript.js` there is a filename change and `node` itself may refer to something else

Answer (score 5):

Either run your file like

`node <your_file>.js`

or  add this on top
`#!/usr/bin/env node`